# How can we create a record of an object which is part of a managed package, via Apex?

Tags: apex, managed-package

I have recently installed a managed package in my org, and I want to create records of an object which is a component of this managed package, via apex. Right now I am unable to do so, because I guess I am not using the Namespace prefix correctly. Below is what I am trying to do :

FYI, Package Namespaceprefix is "NEILON", and API Name of the object is "NEILON__Folder__c"

The code which I tried :

```
NEILON__Folder__c objS3Folder = new NEILON__Folder__c();
    objS3Folder.NEILON__Parent__c = 'a2F0w0000004qKWEAY';
    objS3Folder.Name = 'Loan Application Sample Folder';
insert objS3Folder;
```

Error Message :

```
Line: 1, Column: 1
Invalid type: NEILON__Folder__c
```

I have also tried using `NEILON__NEILON__Folder__c`, and `NEILON.NEILON__Folder__c`, but nothing works.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Code seems proper, its complaining about object name. From Salesforce setup go to the object and verify the object's API name.

Comment: @Raul, The API Name is the same as displayed on the object detail screen. For strange reasons, I could not locate this object when I try to Open Resource from Developer Console, as well. I have attached a screenshot of the Object Detail Page above.

Comment: Did you check if you have object level access to this object?

Comment: @balindersingh, Yes, I have full CRUD Access on this object.

Comment: I would also check if you have a valid license to use that managed package

Comment: It should not complain at compile time, even if you dont have tge permission.

Comment: Have you ever solved this?